# Regex for even index replacement with asterisk in email

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I want to replace letter of even indexes with asterisk (*) in my email **username** before **@** sign using Regular expression.

I made regex but it is once work with even or work with odd length of username in email.

I want a single regex to handle both the expression
First letter must visible all the time in given email.

Please help using regex.

> Example: username@example.com

```
    Regex: Works with odd length username input Expression: (?!^).(?=([^.]([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})*)@) 
    Input : username1@example.com
    Output: u*e*n*m*1@example.com

    Regex: Works with Even length username input Expression: (?!^).(?=(([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})*)@) 
    Input : username@example.com
    Output: u*e*n*m*@example.com
```

But I want a single expression for both kind of username length email.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why use regex?.

Comment: Javascript or c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex `/(\w)(\w)(?=.*@)/g` with substitution `$1*`

```js
console.log('username1@example.com'.replace(/(\w)(\w)(?=.*@)/g,'$1*'))
console.log('username@example.com'.replace(/(\w)(\w)(?=.*@)/g,'$1*'))
```

Comment: but why you need to use regex?

Comment: No need to capture the even index character as you're not using it, `(\w)\w(?=.*@)` will do the same

Comment: @PreetamJakhmola glad to help. You can [accept this answer by click the checkmark in the left](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex for this, you can use LINQ to select the characters you want based on their index from the username:

```
var username = "username1@example.com".Split('@')[0];
var asterisked = string.Concat(username.Select((x,i) => i % 2 == 1 ? '*' : x));
```

Will return `u*e*n*m*1`

```
var username = "username1@example.com".Split('@')[0];
var asterisked = string.Concat(username.Select((x,i) => i % 2 == 0 ? '*' : x));
```

Will return `*s*r*a*e*`

(Assuming you're using C#)

Comment: May be we have different ways to do it. but this is just to prove it can be done in regex. Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

Using C# you could make use of the `\G` anchor and a capturing group and use a negated character class to not match a whitespace char or @.

Use a lookahead to make sure that there is only a single @ char present.

```
\G([^\s@])[^\s@](?=[^\s@]*@[^\s@]+(?!\S))
```

- `\G` Assert position at the end of previous match (At the start)
- `([^\s@])` Capture in **group 1** matching any char exept a whitespace char or @
- `[^\s@]` Match not a whitespace char or @
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is at the right is

  - `[^\s@]*@` Matches 0+ times any char except a whitspace char or @, then match @
  - `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or @
  - `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is a non whitespace char
- `)` Close positive lookahead

In the replacement use

```
$1*
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cG%28%5b%5e%5cs%40%5d%29%5b%5e%5cs%40%5d%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%5cs%40%5d*%40%5b%5e%5cs%40%5d%2b%28%3f!%5cS%29%29&i=username1%40example.com&r=%241*) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/692U8g)

[image]

For example

```
string[] strings = { "File name without 3 digit end.jpg",
        "username1@example.com",
        "username@example.com",                
        "username1@example@example.com",
        "username1@",
        "test",
        };

String pattern = @"\G([^\s@])[^\s@](?=[^\s@]*@[^\s@]+(?!\S))";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string substitution = @"$1*";
foreach(string str in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str, substitution));
}
```

Output

```
u*e*n*m*1@example.com
u*e*n*m*@example.com
username1@example@example.com
username1@
test
```